# percentage table with missing categories

Tags: r, percentage, do.call

I am trying to calculate the percentage of 0,1,2,3 of each column in r using a combination of `prop.table` & `do.call`.

```
tblpercent <- function(x){
  round(prop.table(table(x)),4)
}

do.call(cbind,lapply(A,tblpercent))
```

However, some of the columns do not contain the full set of 0-3, for example, the data looks like A:

```
A <- data.frame(matrix( 
  c(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,0,3,3,3), 
  nrow=6, ncol=3,  byrow = TRUE))
```

And it will return error like this:

```
      X1     X2     X3
0 0.1667 0.3333 0.1667
1 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333
2 0.1667 0.3333 0.5000
3 0.3333 0.3333 0.1667
```

I understand the error is due to missing 0 in X2, 1 in X3 so the percentage returned contain only 3 fields -- Is it possible to fix this easily, or I should rewrite the entire function?

The correct output should be like this:

```
      X1     X2     X3
0 0.1667 0.0000 0.1667
1 0.3333 0.3333 0.0000
2 0.1667 0.3333 0.3333
3 0.3333 0.3333 0.5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can fix this by making it a `factor` with `levels` specified in the `tblpercent` function

```
 tblpercent <- function(x, Un){
     round(prop.table(table(factor(x, levels = Un))),4)
 }

 Un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(A)))
 do.call(cbind, lapply(A, tblpercent, Un= Un1))
 #   X1     X2     X3
 #0 0.1667 0.0000 0.1667
 #1 0.3333 0.3333 0.0000
 #2 0.1667 0.3333 0.3333
 #3 0.3333 0.3333 0.5000
```

---

Using the OP's function, the output generated with `lapply` can have some missing levels leading to difference in `length` between each of the `list` elements.  So, the `cbind` will not work well.